# sql server query , each cell's value is next cell - 1

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

i have a table like below :

```
id    DateFrom      
--------------------
1     2000/05/01    
2     2000/05/05
3     2000/05/05
4     2000/05/05    
5     2000/05/10    
6     2000/05/15    
7     2000/05/25
```

and i want to make it like this . which DateTo contain the next Date - 1 Day

```
id    DateFrom      DateTo
---------------------------
1     2000/05/01    2000/05/04  
2     2000/05/05    2000/05/09
3     2000/05/05    2000/05/09
4     2000/05/05    2000/05/09
5     2000/05/10    2000/05/14
6     2000/05/15    2000/05/24
7     2000/05/25    null
```

i used RowNumber() function but i didng get any result . can anybody help me how to do it or even from which method or function should i perform my job .
thank you

**Edited.
note : my table has duplicate dates**

Comment: Use `LEAD`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213125.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to use a self-join like this:

```
SELECT 
    t1.id, 
    t1.DateFrom, 
    DATEADD(DAY,-1,t2.DateFrom) AS DateTo
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table1 t2 ON t2.id = t1.id+1
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/967f7/2)

Edit: As you have duplicates, you can use a correlated subquery instead. I've updated the SQL Fiddle to include the second solution:

```
select 
    id, 
    DateFrom, 
    (
        select top 1 dateadd(day,-1,datefrom) 
        from table1 
        where id > t1.id and datefrom > t1.datefrom 
        order by id
    ) as DateTo
from table1 t1
```

Comment: Thank you , its fine but my table has duplicate values as i forgot to note . I edited my question .

Comment: @Arashbahreini See my updated answer, I think it should produce the desired output.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative using `LEAD`:

```
SELECT
  DateFrom, 
  DATEADD(dd, -1, LEAD(DateFrom) OVER (ORDER BY DateFrom)) AS DateTo
FROM SomeTable;
```

[SqlFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9a3b5/8)

**Edit**
If you want to eliminate duplicates, first pass the date data through a DISTINCT filter (e.g. a CTE or Derived Table).

```
WITH cteUniqueDates AS
(
  SELECT DISTINCT DateFrom
  FROM SomeTable
)
SELECT
  DateFrom, 
  DATEADD(dd, -1, LEAD(DateFrom) OVER (ORDER BY DateFrom)) AS DateTo
FROM cteUniqueDates;
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/314ab/2)

Comment: Very compact and nice, but only from SQL 2012 and onwards?

Comment: Yes, although note of course Sql 2014 is out, so isn't cutting edge :)

Comment: Thank you , its fine but my table has duplicate values as i forgot to note . I edited my question .

Comment: @Arashbahreini I've updated - you'll need to scrub the data before applying the range logic.